# How to set text for unique id field selenium python robot framework?

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I want to set a unique id for specific id field, each time I want automated id is generated for this field, I tried to use faker but it didn't work.

```
from Faker import fake    
Wait_And_Input_Text  id:VoyageNumber  fake.id
```

It's putting Faker.ID inside the field not a value. any other ideas to get a unique id each time
like putting datetime in seconds format or something.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:-

```
${Engine_Number}=  Generate Random String  length=6  chars=[LETTERS][NUMBERS]
set test Variable  ${Engine_Number}
log to console  ${Engine_Number}
Wait_And_Input_Text  id:VoyageNumber  ${Engine_Number}
```